# How to forward all traffic over a VPN (without rooting) using Forwarding Routes

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, vpn

I noticed this feature in Android 4.2 but was wondering how you can use it to forward all traffic over a VPN connection? When editing a VPN under advanced settings it has a Traffic Routes option that you can put network identifier in that it will forward traffic for. Most people currently seem to root their phone and use SSH tunnels which seems a bit overkill for such a simple feature.

here's the screenshot of the input box I've mentioned.
[image]

Comment: Could you be a little more specific what "this feature" is and how it is supposed to work? A reference won't hurt either. Together it would make it easier to answer your question :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out you can forward all traffic over the network by entering 0.0.0.0/0

You can then check by doing a google search for your IP and it should now be the public IP of your VPN's gateway

Comment: forwarding all traffic seems to be the default behavior

Comment: confirm, forwarding all traffic is the default behavior.