# How to reroute all traffic from Bluetooth tether to a VPN app

Tags: bluetooth, tethering, vpn

Today i tried to use a Bluetooth Personal Area Network to connect to my phone from my laptop because my phone had a VPN on it. When i went to test my IP address i found that android was not rerouting my Bluetooth traffic through the VPN app like i thought but it was instead going through the WiFi normally.

So how can i make Bluetooth tethering work with my VPN app?

Android version - 4.4.2

[VPN App here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.freevpnintouch&hl=en_GB)

Comment: [Related answer helps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/45403)

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks but that solution is assuming that you have access to the settings for the vpn, since my vpn is made using an app it does not show up in the vpn settings tab, thanks though.

Comment: Looks like this could be a leak in your VPN app or even in that specific version of android itself.

Comment: Suggest you link VPN app used by you in the question to clarify which app

Comment: @ionree I will try another vpn app and update the question with my android version.

Comment: @beeshyams Updating now